# angular 5 router link does not work

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, router

Hello dear developers!

I got stack with a simple problem (i think so)

I have a small menu, with a list of links, these are generated from API.
I have a request to the API and I put an id to router link, like

> `[routerLink]="['/search', item.id]"`

so, for example, we are on the search page if you click link you will be redirected to search with this link id, it works fine, now we are on another page that equals search/search_id, at this page I have the same menu, but when I click link again I will not be redirected to another search/another_search_id, I will stay on the same page, but browser URL is changed (page is not reloading).

I am not sure what pieces of code I should provide, so please let me know where the problem can be and I will provide everything you ask.

> Routing model

```
{
    path: 'search',
    component: SearchComponent,
},
{
    path: 'search/:id',
    component: SearchDetailComponent,
},
```

> Template link

```
<a [routerLink]="['/search', item.id]" 
   class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light" 
   *ngFor='let item of searchHistory'>Name</a>
```

Comment: what do you mean with *page is not reloading*?

Answer (score 2):

¿How are you checking the route changing id param?

When you change a route but only the parameter, the page does not refresh, there is a event in your router to check the parameter change and then change the required data in your component

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.searchId = params['id'];
        // Every time you change the route this event will run and then you can update the required data
      }
    );
  }
```

I hope it helps you